# trouble with reading csv file in rbind, "rt" kind of mistake

Tags: r, rbind

I'm having some trouble getting the file from direcotry even though RStudio has already recognised the file

```
library(readr)
read.csv2(names)
list.files("C:\\Users\\consultor6\\Desktop\\PIBIC\\dados")

names = list.files("C:\\Users\\consultor6\\Desktop\\PIBIC\\dados")
lista = list()

lista[[1]] = read.csv2("201812_ESTBAN.CSV")

for(i in 2:length(names)) {

  lista[[i]] = read.csv2(names[i])

}

base = do.call(what = lista, args = rbind)
```

The error is the following:

> library(readr)
>   read.csv2(names)
>   Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
>   list.files("C:\Users\consultor6\Desktop\PIBIC\dados")
>     [1] "200701_ESTBAN.CSV" "200702_ESTBAN.CSV" "200703_ESTBAN.CSV" "200704_ESTBAN.CSV"
>     [5] "200705_ESTBAN.CSV" "200706_ESTBAN.CSV" "200707_ESTBAN.CSV" "200708_ESTBAN.CSV"
>     [9] "200709_ESTBAN.CSV" "200710_ESTBAN.CSV" "200711_ESTBAN.CSV" "200712_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [13] "200801_ESTBAN.CSV" "200802_ESTBAN.CSV" "200803_ESTBAN.CSV" "200804_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [17] "200805_ESTBAN.CSV" "200806_ESTBAN.CSV" "200807_ESTBAN.CSV" "200808_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [21] "200809_ESTBAN.CSV" "200810_ESTBAN.CSV" "200811_ESTBAN.CSV" "200812_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [25] "200901_ESTBAN.CSV" "200902_ESTBAN.CSV" "200903_ESTBAN.CSV" "200904_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [29] "200905_ESTBAN.CSV" "200906_ESTBAN.CSV" "200907_ESTBAN.CSV" "200908_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [33] "200909_ESTBAN.CSV" "200910_ESTBAN.CSV" "200911_ESTBAN.CSV" "200912_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [37] "201001_ESTBAN.CSV" "201002_ESTBAN.CSV" "201003_ESTBAN.CSV" "201004_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [41] "201005_ESTBAN.CSV" "201006_ESTBAN.CSV" "201007_ESTBAN.CSV" "201008_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [45] "201009_ESTBAN.CSV" "201010_ESTBAN.CSV" "201011_ESTBAN.CSV" "201012_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [49] "201101_ESTBAN.CSV" "201102_ESTBAN.CSV" "201103_ESTBAN.CSV" "201104_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [53] "201105_ESTBAN.CSV" "201106_ESTBAN.CSV" "201107_ESTBAN.CSV" "201108_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [57] "201109_ESTBAN.CSV" "201110_ESTBAN.CSV" "201111_ESTBAN.CSV" "201112_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [61] "201201_ESTBAN.CSV" "201202_ESTBAN.CSV" "201203_ESTBAN.CSV" "201204_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [65] "201205_ESTBAN.CSV" "201206_ESTBAN.CSV" "201207_ESTBAN.CSV" "201208_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [69] "201209_ESTBAN.CSV" "201210_ESTBAN.CSV" "201211_ESTBAN.CSV" "201212_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [73] "201301_ESTBAN.CSV" "201302_ESTBAN.CSV" "201303_ESTBAN.CSV" "201304_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [77] "201305_ESTBAN.CSV" "201306_ESTBAN.CSV" "201307_ESTBAN.CSV" "201308_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [81] "201309_ESTBAN.CSV" "201310_ESTBAN.CSV" "201311_ESTBAN.CSV" "201312_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [85] "201401_ESTBAN.CSV" "201402_ESTBAN.CSV" "201403_ESTBAN.CSV" "201404_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [89] "201405_ESTBAN.CSV" "201406_ESTBAN.CSV" "201407_ESTBAN.CSV" "201408_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [93] "201409_ESTBAN.CSV" "201410_ESTBAN.CSV" "201411_ESTBAN.CSV" "201412_ESTBAN.CSV"
>    [97] "201501_ESTBAN.CSV" "201502_ESTBAN.CSV" "201503_ESTBAN.CSV" "201504_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [101] "201505_ESTBAN.CSV" "201506_ESTBAN.CSV" "201507_ESTBAN.CSV" "201508_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [105] "201509_ESTBAN.CSV" "201510_ESTBAN.CSV" "201511_ESTBAN.CSV" "201512_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [109] "201601_ESTBAN.CSV" "201603_ESTBAN.CSV" "201604_ESTBAN.CSV" "201605_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [113] "201606_ESTBAN.CSV" "201607_ESTBAN.CSV" "201608_ESTBAN.CSV" "201609_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [117] "201610_ESTBAN.CSV" "201611_ESTBAN.CSV" "201612_ESTBAN.CSV" "201701_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [121] "201702_ESTBAN.CSV" "201703_ESTBAN.CSV" "201704_ESTBAN.CSV" "201705_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [125] "201706_ESTBAN.CSV" "201707_ESTBAN.CSV" "201708_ESTBAN.CSV" "201709_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [129] "201710_ESTBAN.CSV" "201711_ESTBAN.CSV" "201712_ESTBAN.CSV" "201801_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [133] "201802_ESTBAN.CSV" "201803_ESTBAN.CSV" "201804_ESTBAN.CSV" "201805_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [137] "201806_ESTBAN.CSV" "201807_ESTBAN.CSV" "201808_ESTBAN.CSV" "201809_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   [141] "201810_ESTBAN.CSV" "201811_ESTBAN.CSV" "201812_ESTBAN.CSV"
>   names = list.files("C:\Users\consultor6\Desktop\PIBIC\dados")
>   lista = list()
>
> lista[[1]] = read.csv2("201812_ESTBAN.CSV")
>   Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file '201812_ESTBAN.CSV': No such file or directory
>
> for(i in 2:length(names)) {
>   +
>   +   lista[[i]] = read.csv2(names[i])
>   +
>   + }
>   Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file '200702_ESTBAN.CSV': No such file or directory
>
> base = do.call(what = lista, args = rbind)
>   Error in do.call(what = lista, args = rbind) : 
>     segundo argumento deve ser uma lista

I'm trying to stack the 143 excel files but need to drop the first three lines from matrixes 2 to 143

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [**How to use appropriate formatting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738) and edit your question.

Comment: have you tried: read_csv function from tidyverse? That is a good library.

Comment: You probably want `names = list.files("C:\\Users\\consultor6\\Desktop\\PIBIC\\dados", full.names=TRUE)` unless that is actually your current working directory because otherwise `list.files` returns relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your `read.csv2`statements will only work if your working directory is set appropriately. At the moment, you're just passing the file name to the function, and if your working directory isn't the containing folder, it won't work.

The easiest solution here is to use `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files` which includes the full path to the file, relative to your current working directory, where applicable.

Changing the `names` definition to the following should fix the problem:

```
names = list.files("C:\\Users\\consultor6\\Desktop\\PIBIC\\dados", full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your files are in the directory `"C:\\Users\\consultor6\\Desktop\\PIBIC\\dados"`
and are correctly found by `list.files()`.

However, when you try to read in the files, you forgot to add this path:

```
lista[[1]] = read.csv2("201812_ESTBAN.CSV")
```

Hence `read.csv2` looks for the samples in your current working directory and can not find them (you can check the working directory with `getwd()`).